# With optional time $T$ on $\mathscr{F}_t$, and $T_n = \frac{k}{2^n}$ on $\{ \frac{k-1}{2^n} \le T < \frac{k}{2^n} \}$, show $T_n$ is a stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, stopping-times, filtrations

> Let $T$ be an optional time for the filtration $\{ \mathscr{F}_t \}_{t \ge 0}$, and define the sequence of random times $T_n$ by:
>
> \begin{align*}
>   T_n = T = \infty \; \text{on} \; \{T = \infty\}, \; \; T_n = \frac{k}{2^n} \; \text{on} \; \left\{ \frac{k-1}{2^n} \le T < \frac{k}{2^n} \right\} \\
> \end{align*}
>
> Show that $T_n$ are discrete stopping times for the discrete filtration $\{ \mathscr{F}_{\frac{k}{2^n}} \}_k$.

Considering the finite case first. For any finite $T$, integer $n \ge 1$, integer $k \ge 0$, we have:

\begin{align*}
  \left\{ \frac{k-1}{2^n} \le T < \frac{k}{2^n} \right\} = \left\{ T < \frac{k-1}{2^n} \right\}^c \cap \left\{ T < \frac{k}{2^n} \right\} \in \mathscr{F}_{\frac{k}{2^n}} \\
  \left\{ T_n - \frac{1}{2^n} \le T < T_n \right\} = \left\{ T_n \le T + \frac{1}{2^n} \right\} \cap \{T_n \le T\}^c \in \mathscr{F}_{\frac{k}{2^n}} \\
\end{align*}

Since the above is for any $T$, can we just set $T = \frac{k}{2^n}$ to get $\{T_n \le \frac{k}{2^n}\} \in \mathscr{F}_{\frac{k}{2^n}}$ which would give the desired conclusion?

Am I close?

Comment: \begin{align*}
  \left\{ \frac{k-1}{2^n} \le T < \frac{k}{2^n} \right\} = \left\{ T < \frac{k-1}{2^n} \right\}^c \cap \left\{ T < \frac{k}{2^n} \right\} \in \mathscr{F}_{\frac{k}{2^n}} \\
 \\
\end{align*} finishes the proof. I don't what you are doing after that.

Comment: That doesn't show that $T_n$ is a stopping time. We need to show that $\{T_n \le \frac{k}{2n} \} \in \mathscr{F}_{\frac{k}{2n}}$

Comment: Am I missing something? How does that finish the proof that $T_n$ is a stopping time?

Comment: $\{T_n=\frac k {2^{n}}\}\in \mathcal F_{k/2^{n}}$ so $T_n$ is a stopping time. That is the definition.